# Chrome address bar leave a white space on mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have an issue on my mobile site with the address bar of Google Chrome. I have a fixed navbar on my website and at the moment i scroll down and the address bar dissapear, when i open my menu, a white space (size of the address bar) appears at the bottom and i need to scroll up to make the address bar appear thus removing the white space. This is my menu css:

```
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

Other web browsers are working fine on mobile, what can i do to get rid of that address bar blank space?

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem after upgrading my Chrome. I got it resolved by changing position to fixed.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing

Comment: Yes!! This finally worked. For the record, I put everything in one root div with width and height 100%, and fixed position.

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Links go dead over time. Either form your own answer using your link as a reference, or delete this altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @jahooma THANK YOU! I solved a React Chrome Mobile Position Fixed issue thanks to you :)

```#root{
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height:100%;
    }```